# Create GUID partition table (GPT) during Ubuntu Server install

Tags: server, partitioning, gpt, alternate

On a computer with a new empty hard drive of capacity < 2 TB, I install Ubuntu Server with the **standard text-mode installer**. I choose to manually partition the disk. Then I can create a new empty partition table. This will be a legacy partition table. However, I want a GPT one, but I didn't find a way to select it.

I've tried to switch to a text console via <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>. However, the command `gdisk` is not available (neither is `fdisk`).

I know that I could boot some live linux first to create the partition table (which seems unnecessarily cumbersome). So my question is explicitly about the standard Ubuntu Server text-mode installer. Is there a way to create a GUID partition table (GPT) during the install?

Answer (score 8):

Test this:

You switch to a text console via <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Try to create a partition start GNU parted as follows:

```
sudo -i
parted /dev/sda
```

Output:

```
GNU Parted 2.3
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted)
```

Creates a new GPT disklabel i.e. partition table:

```
mklabel gpt
```

Sample outputs:

```
Warning: The existing disk label on /dev/sda will be destroyed and all data on this disk will be lost. Do you want to continue?
Yes/No? yes
```

Next, set the default unit to TB, enter:

```
unit TB
```

To create a 2TB partition size, enter:

```
mkpart primary 0.00TB 2.00TB
```

To print the current partitions, enter:

```
print
```

Sample outputs:

```
Model: ATA ST33000651AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2.00TB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      0.00TB  2.00TB  2.00TB  ext4         primary
```

Quit and save the changes, enter:

```
quit
```

Use the mkfs.ext4 command to format the file system, enter:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I will check if `parted` is available from the Server installer text console.

Comment: @kyodake, @azimut: no, unfortunately, `parted` is not available in the Server installer text console :-(

Comment: After some more research it is possible (at least on the 16.04 Xenial server installer): From the server installer you can pop to a different console (e.g. using Alt-F2) and run `udpkg -i /cdrom/pool/main/p/parted/parted-udeb_3.2-15_amd64.udeb`

Comment: @ph0t0nix: Thanks. I will try that at my next install after the official release of 16.04

Comment: @ph0t0nix : excellent tip, which also works on a 14.04.4 CD/ISO, except for a slightly different path (due to different version). Use `udpkg -i /cdrom/pool/main/p/parted/parted-udeb_2.3-19ubuntu1.14.04.1_amd64.udeb`

Answer (score 6):

I suppose a direct 'yes' solution to your question is to ensure your machine **boots in UEFI-only mode**.  This worked flawlessly for me on a SuperMicro X11 mainboard with the official 14.04.4 server installer.  I did have to change the BIOS boot mode from "DUAL" (which also allows "LEGACY" boots) to "UEFI".

This yielded a `/dev/sda` root disk that was GPT partitioned (with a bootable fat32 partition type `EF00`) without any manual intervention.  I was also able to adjust the "guided" partitioning - just because I wanted different sizes and layout, there was no need to do anything special relating to GPT.

It would be interesting to know if there are any downsides to booting in UEFI mode.  Can't help but think the technology's been around long enough for issues to have been ironed out...

[image: see also attached screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Fdisk does not work for GPT, currently.
But parted does. Or you can just easily install gdisk.

At the current time the installer does not let you select. At some point over 1.5TB (if drive is unpartitioned) or is UEFI it defaults to GPT, otherwise it defaults to MBR and is not otherwise selectable.

Convert to msdos or gpt, if you have data may be destructive, so have good backups:

```
sudo parted /dev/sda
mklabel msdos/gpt
quit
```

You can easily install gdisk:

```
sudo apt-get install gdisk
```

http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/

GPT Advantages (older but still valid)  see post#2 by srs5694:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1457901

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GUID_Partition_Table#Advantages_of_GPT

Comment: The question was how to create a GPT **in the Ubuntu Server text-mode installer**.

Comment: @azimut This answer provides you with a way of using `parted` to create the GPT in a tty (which is what you tried with `fdisk` which won't work as it doesn't support GPT).  If you want, I can provide you with a simpler answer but that would just read "No, from the text-mode installer itself it is currently not possible to do this" and then close your question as "off-topic: bugs should be filed to launchpad"...  Leave me a comment if that’s preferable to someone actually trying to help you...  **:P  ;-)**

Comment: @Fabby: Right, I gave a "yes or no" question, and that is basically what I wanted as an answer: Either "no" or "yes" + how. I wrote twice that this question is explicitely about the standard Ubuntu Server installer, so I think it's only fair to expect that this point isn't completely ignored.

Comment: @azimut: **:D**  I understand now! **;-)**  Well, you've got it in a comment below the answer now!  :P  ;-)  **oldfred**: please [edit] your answer and start with "No, this is not possible, but here's a workaround:" and leave all the rest intact.  After that, I think someone is going to push the little sad grey check-mark and turn it a beautiful green hue...  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

To find the gdisk package:
`find /cdrom | grep gdisk`

To install it:
`udpkg -i /cdrom/<blah>`

You will need to repeat this a couple of times to install `libstdc++`, `libgcc_s` and perhaps one or two other shared libraries that are missing from the Ubuntu Server 15.10 installer image, before the installed gdisk package will run.

You'll get a couple of errors while installing shared libraries because `udpkg` is not `apt-get` and does not resolve dependencies.  Ignore the errors, gdisk will still work.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way for me was to boot into the the existing installation :

`apt-get install gdisk
gdisk /dev/vda`

& write (option `o` in `gdisk`) a **GPT** partition table (which allocated `1 MiB` of space at the beginning & end of the disk & preserved a protected copy of the **MBR**).

I then **rebooted** from the CD & chose `Rescue Mode`& mounted the `root` partition from the existing installation & ran :

`/sbin/gdisk /dev/vda`

& created the `gpt` partitions setting the correct partition types :

[image]

You will need to **reboot** the machine again so the kernel reads the new partition table & begin the installation.

During installation I set :

***Partition 1:***

`1 MiB EF02`   as filesystem type `reserved-bios`

***Partition 2:***

`250 MiB EF00` as `ext4` with `noatime,nodiratime` mounted @ `/boot` & marked `bootable`

Comment: Thanks for this.  I haven't attempted it but does this method allow preserving the existing installation or do you have to re-install on top of the manually created partitions?

Comment: @sxc731 - you will need to reinstall